# How to make an AJAX GET request to play a folder of videos?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, video

My problem is when I want to create an AJAX GET Request to play each of the videos in order automatically.  I want them to automatically play each video in the retrieved playlist using addEventListener, the video object's src property, load and play methods.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<title>Play Videos</title>
</head>
<body>

<video controls width="400px" height="200px">

</video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where are the videos? I can only see that you have loaded jquery and some validation lib.

Comment: This is the playlist `[
    {
        "video": "video/preroll"
    },
    {
        "video": "video/areyoupopular"
    },
    {
        "video": "video/destinationearth"
    }
]`  I can't upload the videos here.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to use the `<video>`  tag you have to define a `src` attribute, with a valid url. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: var position = 0;
var playlist;
var video;

window.onload = function() {
 playlist = ["video/preroll", 
    "video/areyoupopular", 
    "video/destinationearth"];
 video = document.getElementById('video');
 video.addEventListener("ended", nextVideo,false);

 video.src = playlist[position] + getFormatExtension();
 video.load();
 video.play();
};

Comment: function nextVideo() {
 position++;
 if (position >= playlist.length) {
  position = 0;
 }
 video.src = playlist[position] + getFormatExtension();
 video.load();
 video.play();
}

function getFormatExtension() {
    if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4") != "") {
        return ".mp4";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/ogg") != "") {
        return ".ogv";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/webm") != "") {
        return ".webm";
    }
}

Comment: The 2 above comments are my Javascript file, which I need to know how to tie to the HTML page, so that the videos can play automatically

Answer (score 0):

To play a video automatically you need to set the [autoplay](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_video_autoplay.asp) property of the video tag.
Then change the content of your video tag with jQuery dynamically.

By the way you have a typo here: